# How to fade out element using ng-hide with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css-animations, ng-hide

I can currently show/hide an element according to a boolean condition in my controller. How can I fade the element out if the condition is true instead of just instantly hiding it?

```
<div id='conversion-image' ng-hide="pages.length > 0">
    generating pages...
    <br />
    <img src='Images/ajax-loader-blue.gif' />
</div>
```

I also already have the ngAnimate dependancy included as well.

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngAnimate"]);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it with CSS and `ng-animate` as the following:

```css
.fade-out.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade-out.ng-hide-add, .fade-out.ng-hide-remove {
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
}

.check-element {
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="animations.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular-animate.js"></script>      
</head>

<body ng-app="ngAnimate">
  Hide: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" aria-label="Toggle ngHide"><br />
  <div class="check-element fade-out" ng-hide="checked">
    I fade out when your checkbox is checked.
  </div>
</body>
```

[Angular `ng-hide` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide):

> Overriding .ng-hide
>
> By default, the .ng-hide class will style the element with display: none !important. If you wish to change the hide behavior with ngShow/ngHide, you can simply overwrite the styles for the .ng-hide CSS class. Note that the selector that needs to be used is actually .ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate) to cope with extra animation classes that can be added.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following class **class="animate-show animate-hide"**

```
<div id='conversion-image' class="animate-show animate-hide" ng-
   hide="model.transaction.selectedDocument.pages.length > 0">
     generating pages...
    <br />
   <img src='Images/ajax-loader-blue.gif' />
</div>
```

**Add the styles below**

```
<style>
    .animate-show,.animate-hide {
       -webkit-transition:all linear 1s;
       -moz-transition:all linear 1s;
       -ms-transition:all linear 1s;
       -o-transition:all linear 1s;
       transition:all linear 1s;
  }

   .animate-show.ng-hide-remove,
    .animate-hide.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active {
        opacity: 0;
        display: block !important;
    }

    .animate-hide.ng-hide-add,
    .animate-show.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
        opacity: 1;
        display: block !important;

</style>
```

Here is a plunker example http://plnkr.co/edit/VoWwmHK57wtuyGl6npr0?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the fade class in your div and add a button to toggle your condition to see the animation on hide. You can use your own condition in ng-hide = "your_own_condition"

```
<div id='conversion-image' class="fade" ng-hide="condition">
    generating pages...
    <br />
    <img src='Images/ajax-loader-blue.gif' />
</div>

<button ng-click="condition=!condition">Toggle</button>

<style>
.fade.ng-hide {
  transition:0.5s linear all;
  opacity:0;
}
</style>
```